# Touch position in WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I have a WebBrowser in my application, I need to know where the position of primary touch is in the screen.

this event not fired in the WebBrowser:

```
Touch.FrameReported += new TouchFrameEventHandler(Touch_FrameReported);
```

and also this:

```
GestureService.GetGestureListener(webBrowser1);
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add JavaScript function to your page that will call `window.external.notify` to send touch position from `WebBrowser` to your C# code. You will need to subscribe to `WebBrowser.ScriptNotify` event and allow JavaScript execution in `WebBrowser`.

Comment: I cant get touch position in JavaScript, can you explain me?

Answer (score 1):

[The PhoneGap Wp7](http://phonegap.com/2011/09/08/announcing-phonegap-for-windows-phone-mango/) page claims that this is not possible from a WebBrowser control. See the Gotchas section towards the bottom:

"IE9 does not expose touch events, or even mouse events to JavaScript. The only UI event that is available to your code is the click event."